# finding visible elements with jqlite

Tags: jquery, jqlite

I'm trying to write a unit test in Jasmine to look for an element that becomes visible after a button is clicked.  The problem I am having is the `find` finds hidden elements to.

```
        var visibleUndoButtons = 0;
        var undoButtons = element.find(".btn-undo");
        undoButtons.each((index, value) => {
           if ($(this).css("display", "none")) {
               console.log("none");
           } else {
               visibleUndoButtons++;
           }
        });
        expect(visibleUndoButtons).toEqual(1);
```

Can jqlite do what I am asking it?  Or is there a better way to find either the visible elements or invisible elements that have a specific class?

Comment: What about the "standard" jQuery `:visible` selector: `element.find( '.btn-undo:visible' );`

Comment: @feeela I'm trying to not import jquery and just use jqlite.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just did:

```
it("should not hide any of the checkboxes", inject(function ($document) {
  $document.find('body').append(element);
  angular.forEach(element.find('.check-box'), function (checkBox) {
    expect(angular.element(checkBox).css('display')).toBe('inline');
  });
}));
```

My css visibility rule comes from an external stylesheet (as opposed to being inline), which probably is the reason for the .css() method to return an empty string if I omit the

```
$document.find('body').append(element);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, my external css isn't included in karma, so that can't be the reason. Anyway, it works as expected only when I append the element to the document. Maybe someone could shed a light on why?